# Laravel return value is inserting newline at the start

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

For some reason it seems like my return value is getting a newline inserted preceeding it. I have similar code that does not return a newline preceeding my return value, and I have tried just about everything to make the code the same to avoid the newline to no avail.

I am not sure why this is happening and I am afraid to accept the newline character into my comparison expressions because I am afraid it will not be consistent...Hoping someone can shed some light on this.

**Controller**

```
  public function addToWaitlist()
  {
       //omitted irrlevent code
       return("success");
  }
```

**Jquery**

```
$.get( '{{route('addToWaitlist')}}', data, function(result){

    alert(result == "\nsuccess"); //ALERT BOX SHOWS TRUE

    if(result == 'success'){
        //add seesion data 'attendee added to waitlist'
        alert('attendee added to waitlist');
        location.reload();
    }
    else {
        //display session data error
        alert('error attendee not added to waitlist');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure all of the PHP files involved omit the `?>` tag at the bottom of the file, and have no newlines before the initial `<?php` tag.

In my experience, unexpected newlines at the start of PHP output are usually caused by situations like this in your files:

```
                                                                                            // comment to make this empty line show
<?php
    // file goes here
?>

                                                                                            // comment to make this empty line show
```

Notice the initial newline and two trailing newlines at the end of the file -- they are interpreted as HTML and output as newlines.

The best practice is to omit the closing `?>` tag on all PHP files, and ensure the opening `<?php` tag is on line 1.

Comment: I had an empty line before the `<?php` at the start of one of my Model files which was causing the problem! I will mark your answer as correct. Maybe you can edit your answer to add to check for the empty line at the start too. THANKS!